# Implementing REST API in Angular

Tags: angularjs, api, rest

I'm learning how to implement APIs in angular and I came across a term: "REST API".  I did some research and I was unsure if REST API was different from the other APIs I was messing around with.  I created a program using the OMDBApi, which is just a way to fetch movie data and I just fetched the json data with `$http.get` requests like `"http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + title + "&y=&plot=short&r=json"`.

Would I fetch data the same way using a REST api?  I was slightly confused because on the site I was looking at they emphasized a lot that it was a "REST API" and the URI they provided looked like this: `http://myhost.com:8085/rest/api/latest/`.  This URI is a little bit different from the others I've come across.  Can someone please explain how I would use this API?

Reference: https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/rest-apis/bamboo-rest-resources

Comment: REST is working with json. that's all

Answer (score 0):

REST (**RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer) is just an architectural style used when creating an API.

In Angular, you'll most likely still use `$http` to make requests just as you have been. Whether you use query parameters (`?somevalue=something`) just depends on the API you're using. For the specific documentation you link to, it looks like you'll use query parameters as well.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming?rq=1) has more information on REST in general.